# Analogs of the Weil conjectures for non-archimedian fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-analysis, non-archimedean-fields

Suppose that $X$ is a smooth and proper variety defined over a perfect non-archimedian valued field $k$ of characteristic $p$.  Then one can consider the action of Frobenius on crystalline cohomology.

Are there any predictions/known results for the behavior of this operator?

Edit: as pointed out in the comment below, this operator is semi-linear over the fraction field of $W(k)$.

Remark 1: If $X$ were defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$, then Weil conjectures predict/imply that the eigenvalues are algebraic numbers (and there is also a statement about the norm of the eigenvalues). I'm wondering about analogous statements for varieties over perfect non-archimedian fields.

Comment: The Frobenius on crystalline cohomology is a semi-linear map, so its eigenvalues are not really well defined. Also, crystalline cohomology is a $W(k)$-module so it's not clear what extra structure you can get from the assumption that $k$ is a valued field. (The $p$-adic valuations of the eigenvalues are well-defined and these satisfy the same properties (for any perfect field $k$) that they do when $k$ is a finite field.)

Comment: @naf Thanks a lot for this comment! I have corrected the statement of the question.  Do you know a reference for the statement that the $p$-adic valuations of the eigenvalues satisfy the same properties as when $k$ is a finite field?

Comment: See the survey article "Crystalline cohomology" by Illusie in Proceedings of Symposia in Pure Mathematics, 55, vol. 1.

Comment: @naf Thank you for this reference!